# Is it possible to run appium server as a service in Linux OS like Ubuntu?

Tags: appium

I've googled the topic but no result. One alternative way is to use Java client to start appium server programatically. However, I am using Python as my test script. It seems the Python client does not have such APIs.

So, I want to know if it is possible to run appium server as a service, so that I can use the following command to start/stop it:

## service appium-server start

## service appium-server stop

Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can run appium server in any machine, but you need to mention ip address and port through that you can access the appium. the same lot of cloud systems are running like sauce lab and testdroid.

Comment: Thanks for the information. but I want to run the appium server on the same machine with the test code. So I want to use the service command to start/stop appium in my scripts. It seems appium has no such features.

Comment: you can run the appium server from command line : appium &